# Weird problem in react: (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql

I'm currently working on a MERNG app, and i was doing the setup in the fronted, and, when i ran npm run start, this error suddenly appeared

```
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Compiling...
```

i've searched for this problem, and i found that, you should delete node_modules, then run npm intall, i tried, didn't work

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "styled-icons": "^10.33.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my index, i put there my apolloProvider and my redux setup

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ApolloProvider from "./ApolloProvider";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { reducer } from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>{ApolloProvider}</Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is my apollo provider

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  createHttpLink
} from "@apollo/client";

import App from "./App";

const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:5000"
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

What is going on with my react app? i'm mad at this because it came out of nowhere, any clue how to fix this? And thank your four time comunnity !

Comment: Why the hell is your build trying to access the operating system's pagefile? That's an extremely weird bug. I hope this is not some malware trying to find confidential information (such as passwords) in your pagefile ... you may want to instrument chokidar to print a stacktrace to find out which dependency did this, and carefully check whether the code is benign - and if not, how it came to be installed on your system.

Comment: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1037

Comment: Yeah, i hope it's not something trying to hack me LOL, but it might be that, i don't know how it happend, bul i'll find out !